# Is it possible to split vendor.js file (multiple vendor.js files) so that initial load time can be reduced?

Tags: angularjs, build, gulp, production

I want to split my vendor file so that it only loads angular and oclazyloading libs at initial load so that initial loading time is reduced. All the other dependencies can be loaded later, maybe with another vendor file. I looked around and many suggested webpack. But I am using gulp and I need to use gulp because it's what has been used over a long time and a lot of tasks have already been written in it. It would be a pain to rewrite it in webpack.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any solution for this.?

Comment: @AbijithAjayan Honestly, I don't remember if they ever found a solution for this. This was a very long time ago and I don't work with those technologies anymore :|

Comment: Ok Thanks for your valuable reply. If you got any solution. please reply here. Because am stuck with this splitting method